# JQuery ID selector for auto generated through php loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, loops

I'm new to JQuery, therefore I'm having difficulty catching element ID's that are generated automatically through my PHP loop.

My question is how can I catch those automatically generated id's in JQuery, how to use loop in JQuery to catch a unique id, btw my id format is `id="divAddressSet1", id="divAddressSet2"` and so on. How I would be able to catch `name(divAddressSet)+a unique number` attached with each id in JQuery

Any idea?

Comment: Use a common class then use class selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [`attribute starts with selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) at this context,

```
$('[id^="divAddressSet"]')
```

Or do one thing, while generating those elements, just attach a common class to that. And grab those elements with the help of [`class selector`](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) like,

```
$('.commonClass')
```

---

Since your elements are created at runtime, use [`event-delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) as below,

```
$(document).on("click" ,'.commonClass',function() {

});
```

And as a special note, replace, the closest static parent to `.commonClass` with `document`. If you don't do that then the bound click event would get fired only after the `propagation` reaches to the `document` [$(**document**).on(...)]. Document is the root of the DOM, so it would cause performance lagging if you have a quite bigger dom structure..

Comment: Thanks @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy for your effort, btw what is that hat symbol for? if i may ask for my knowledge

Comment: @UsmanSharifAmjadKhan That symbol would represent the attribute starts with selector, read the link provided to learn more. And You should use event-delegation for the elements which are created dynamically..

Answer (score 2):

use `event delegation`

```
$(document).on("click" ,'[id^="divAddressSet"]',function() {

       alert(this.id);   
});
```

for id selector you use prefix "`#`"
for class selector use "`.`"

Comment: thank you @Sudharsan it worked, but how would I hide all those ID's on page load, which will be handled with (toggled on off) via a checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Selectors Example :

Starts with a given string (for example divAddressSet),

```
$("[id^='divAddressSet']")
```

If you want to select elements which id contains a given string :

```
$("[id*='divAddressSet']")
```

Script

```
$(document).on("click" ,'[id^="divAddressSet"]',function() {  });
```

OR

```
$(document).on("click" ,'.yourclass',function() {  });
```